# Laravel и маршрутизация без указания явного url?

Tags: laravel

Планируется построить мини CMS на Laravel. Среди прочего, у пользователя должна быть возможность задавать url материалов/групп-материалов через админку.

Имеется ли возможность не указывать явный url в маршрутизаторе, а скажем брать его из БД?

Comment: Ну вы можете переопределить роутер по умолчанию. Добавить туда запрос в БД

Comment: @ArchDemon это правильное решение задачи? Просто на данный момент я особо не вникал в идеологию Laravel, поэтому сразу хочу найти верный путь...

Comment: Лучше, конечно, отказаться от маршрутизации из БД. Даже не представляю как может возникнуть необходимость в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Роуты из бд которые создают пользователи вполне хорошая идея для CMS, вот примерно как можно решить Ваш вопрос:

Нужно создать таблицу наподобие этой:

```
// Страница для динамических страниц
id | slug | title | page_content
```

Создайте модель `Page`:

```
class Page extends Eloquent {
    // ...

    // Динамический локальный scope который возвращает страницу ища ее по  slug, подробнее: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes
    public function scopeOfSlug($query, $slug)
    {
        return $query->where('slug', $slug);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Затем создайте контроллер для `CRUD`, вы можете использовать контроллер ресурсов или обычный контроллер, например, обычный `PageController`:

```
class PageController extends BaseController {

    // Тут Ваши методы для добавления, удаления, редактирования и показа

    // создание страницы
    public function create()
    {
        // создает страницу по данным из запроса, не помешала бы валидация через FormRequest
        $page = Page::create(request()->all());
    }

    // Показать страницу по slug
    public function show($slug = 'home')
    {
        $page = Page::ofSlug($slug)->first(); // поиск страницы по slug 

        return view('pages.index', compact(['page']));
    }
}
```

Файл представления `views/page/index.blade.php:`

```
@extends('layouts.master')

{{-- Можете добавить другие части, например, меню--}}

@section('content')
    {{ $page->page_content }}
@stop
```

Чтобы показывать страницы, создайте такой маршрут:

```
// можнос сделать как page/{slug} или просто /{slug}
Route::get('/{slug}', 'PageController@show')->name('page.show');
```

Чтобы получить доступ к странице Вы можете написать:

```
http://example.com/home
http://example.com/about
```

Надеюсь это поможет.